# Grails could not resolve createAlias inside namedQuery

Tags: hibernate, grails

I want to have some LEFT JOIN inside the namedQuery. In the example it should find all **A** objects where objectB is null or objectB.name has a specific value.

But the alias "objectBAlias" can not be resolved:

```
class A{

    B objectB

    static namedQueries = {

        someNamedQuery {
            createAlias("objectB", "objectBAlias", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
            or{
               isNull("objectBAlias")
               eq("objectBAlias.name", "some text")
            }
        }
    }
```

It throws:

> could not resolve property: objectBAlias of: A

Am I missing something? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem. But to solve your problem just change your code slightly:

```
someNamedQuery {
    createAlias("objectB", "objectBAlias", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    or{
       isNull("objectB")
       eq("objectBAlias.name", "some text")
    }
}
```